# how to get child of select tag when i load option tag dynamically with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

hi this is my select tag in html

```
<select class="form-control city-select"></select>
```

and this is script

```
$.post('../select-city.php',{id: id_province},function (e) {

   $('.city-select').append(e);
});
```

and my option tag will load with post method and i can see with 
browser

when i get console.log() this :`console.log($(".city-select").children().length);`
my console show 0 why ?
how can i fix it to show real number !
please help me

Comment: do you mean the options?

Comment: What is the ajax response? also where are you checking the count?

Comment: Can you please provide a jsfiddle demo?

Comment: yes option tag is child of select #JayeshChitroda

Comment: @PranavCBalan on browser shows my option

Comment: @alirezavalipour : please share the value of `e` inside success callback...

Answer (score 0):

One thing to be consider, you are appending your options at run time, might be that is the case you are not getting option .length. Make sure, check the length after loading all your option and after that check length.
Try using like this,

```
  console.log($(".city-select").find('option').length);
```

Comment: Before checking length, check weather the HTML inside the select is present or not ?  Like this, console.log($(".city-select").html());

Comment: Or might be the case, the same class has been declared some where else in the page. If so , then try with more specific, by using tag name or id.

Comment: my select tag is exist in my html

Comment: and there is no same class in my page